# How to use LocationRequest? Because direct constructor is not working nor .create()

Tags: java, google-maps, android-fragments, currentlocation

I am trying to get current location in a map fragment but unable to do so because LocationRequest.create() is not wokring. Neither works:

```
LocationRequest l = new LocationRequest();
```

OR

```
LocationReuest l = LocationRequest.create();
```

My MapsFragment.java:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationRequest;

public class MapsFragment extends SupportMapFragment {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
}
```

My build.gradle (app level):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.niqo01.rxplayservices:rx-play-services-location:0.4.0'
}
```

I have cleaned and rebuilded the app but it doesn't works.
Please give a solution for this or just a code to make sure I get current location on a google map in a fragment

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong class.

instead of using the class LocationRequest that is part of android.location package write the following in your imports section:

```
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
```